# Android Studio does not perform automatic error detection

Tags: android-studio, ide

I'm using Android Studio 1.1.0 in Mac OS X 10.10. I noticed that when I wrote code like:

```
public void;
```

or even:

```
+ (bad) thisObjectiveCCodeShouleNeverCompileInJava:(ButSomehow *)itsNotComplaining
```

Android Studio didn't complain. Once I built it, Gradle showed the error, but the editor pane still did not. I attempted to use `Navigate` > `Next Highlighted Error`, I got the following balloon over my text cursor:

[image: A manilla-color balloon reading "Error analysis in progress"]

I let it sit for up to half an hour and still, no errors or warnings were ever highlighted. Similarly, placing the text cursor in/on a variable name does not highlight its usages in the file (but `Edit` > `Find` > `Highlight Usages in File` works fine).

I tried updating to 1.2.x, but I get this:

[image: The update dialog saying that Android Studio is checking for updates on the stable channel, cannot check now, and is currently on version 1.1.0 (build AI-135.1740770).]

At one point, when attempting to `Make Project`, I got the following:

[image: An internal error from Android Studio, showing a <code>Java Native Exception</code> described as a <code>NullPointerException</code> at <code>sun.lwawt.macosx.CAccessibility.getAccessibleIndexInParent(CAccessibility.java:287)</code>, followed by a stack trace from the underlying Objective C code.]

**What's going on, and is there any way to fix this without reinstalling Android Studio from scratch?**

Comment: Ben you will get better answers by asking on G+ Android Dev Tools community:https://plus.google.com/communities/114791428968349268860 as Google Engineers do answer inquiries there

Comment: @FredGrott https://plus.google.com/115044716297267890703/posts/B62aTqtTPeG posted, but I'd still love a resolution

Comment: Goodness am I glad I didn't abandon this question in favor of Google+ lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of this is because **I had Power Save Mode enabled**. Unchecking this re-enabled error highlighting and other such features.

[image: The "File" menu of Android Studio, showing "Power Save Mode" checked at the bottom]